# Is ダウンアンダー understood by non-Australian Japanese speakers?

Tags: words, slang, loanwords

Firstly, is "ダウンアンダー" the correct spelling? I think it is, based on the Japanese Wikipedia articles [メン・アット・ワーク](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF) and [ツアー・ダウンアンダー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%84%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC)
, but I could be mistaken.

But apart from that, is the average non-Australian Japanese speaker likely to understand the term, which is used as slang to refer to Australia (even though there's plenty of other southern hemisphere countries)?

Comment: Does *anyone* outside of Australia use "down under" to mean Australia? I've never heard it used that way.

Comment: @Blavius that's probably my most common way to refer to the land of kangaroos and koala chlamydia

Comment: @Blavius Quite common in America (at least on the east coast), though perhaps only used jokingly/mockingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer would be a simple 'No'.  Seriously, I do not think that the word 「ダウンアンダー」 would exist in the vocabulary of more than even 1% of us.

The most common name for your country in Japanese is 「オーストラリア」 by a landslide, followed by 「[豪州]{ごうしゅう}」.  In people's daily conversations, it is 「オーストラリア」 nearly 100% of the time.  「豪州」 is kind of "common" in the printed media because it is a neat space-saver.

「ダウンアンダー」?  One used to hear/see the word when Men At Work were popular (But that is like 30 years ago!).  I suppose we just never registered it as a household word.

(I have personally used both 「ダウンアンダー」 and "Down Under" a few times in my conversations with Australians living in Japan, and I seemed to surprise them each time for even using those words actively as a Japanese person who has never been to ダウンアンダー.  This should probably tell you something about how uncommon 「ダウンアンダー」 is around here.)